# loading data everytime the screen opens

Tags: react-native

I am  new to react native and I a have  been working on a project at now stuck at a point need help

Actually I want to call a  function (`_profiledata()`) where ever I navigate to profile page. Basically what I am doing is calling the function in `componentDidMount` but it is only called once

I tried using `componentWillUpdate` but it keep on running as I set state in the `profiledata` function.

The code is given bellow

```js
componentDidMount()
{
  this._profiledata();
  console.log('fordata')
}
```

Comment: What did you use for routing? If you are using react-navigation, your component will NOT unmount when you changing screen so componentDidMount() just be called one time.

Comment: yeah I used react-Navigation

Comment: so is there any way around

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an work around ,

Use this

```
 this._profiledata()
```

On the onPress function of the profile page , example if the profile page is situated on settings page.  Use the onPress function to data when user presses on profile menu under settings page !

And use a activity indicator of show to users , when data is being loaded and fetched ! Once done show the content !

Hope the suggestion helps !

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i am navigating  it from on another page i have a switch account page so once the user switches the account the user send to profile page so how can i call it

Comment: Ya , what's the starting point of the navigation ? Use there! If it's an redirect page add that to the redirect function

Comment: The point is , add the required at the initiation of the profile page . Not on lifecycle methods

Comment: look i am beginner so i am not quite  understanding what you are saying so can you show me some example

Comment: From where your navigating to this profile page ? Explain that scenario

Comment: i have  a page switchaccount  and there is list of buttons for each useraccount and then on onpress of that button i am navigating to profile for the first time it works fine but when i again try to switch account it navigates and shows previous details

Comment: Show the onPress function of the button used on switchaccount list !

Comment: switchaccount(id){
       //some logic
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
      }

Comment: Okay, add this code is `onPress{()=> { this._profiledata()   this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile'); }}`

Comment: but bro profiledata fucntion is on profile page and this onPress function is on switchaccount page

Comment: If thats the case, post your _profiledata function .

Comment: i just load data from sqlite and set the state of profile page

Comment: I think this is what your expecting, check this page https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle. Use Listener to know about the navigation lifecycle. And you can use necessary in componentDidMount() itself if you use this !